# EE Conditionals failing due to '' and ""

Tags: conditionals, low-events

I have this conditional:

```
{if '{spieldaten_datum:first unit="month"}' == 'y'}
 Blabla whatever
{/if}
```

On my mamp environment with php 5.5.10 it all looks fine.

On my live Server with php 5.5.26 a part of the conditional is actually displayed like this:

[image]

I guess this has to do with the nesting of `''` and `""` But why is it working on one environment but not on the other. How do I need to write this?

The tag `{spieldaten_datum:first unit="month"}` is from the low events plugin.

ee version: 2.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled back to v2.6.1 The latest ee v2.10.1 seems to no screw with encoding somehow in that server config.

Answer (score 0):

**Always use duplicate environments between development and production machines**. There are so many environment variables to compare:

1. Apache config
2. Apache version
3. PHP agent config
4. PHP agent version
5. OS environment

Are your operating systems different? Remember that Linux and Windows use **different** line ending characters:

```
Windows: "\r\n"
Linux: "\n"
```

Are you saving your files in Windows set to Windows line-endings and then moving them to a Linux server?

I highly recommend duplicating your development and production environments. This could still be unrelated to this issue, but there is so many variables, and since it's clearly working in one place and not the other, I think we have a fantastic clue to the issue.

**Edit**

Are you sure you have duplicate templates and Low Events (same version please!!) between the two environments? This:

```
{if " == 'y'}
```

looks like this to me:

```
{if 'something-is-not-showing-up-here' == 'y'}
```

Comment: local = mamp mac
live = linux

Comment: I would take the time to launch a duplicate hypervisor to your production environment and use that as a development device. I promise you, you won't even know to thank yourself because you'll automatically avoid so many issues, and be able to generally rule out environment when you hit bugs. But I'll think about your issue and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: And how yould I duplicate a server environement from a shared hoster? I'd say thats nearly impossible.
I checked the rest of the page and the german Umlauts are displayed as `?` so I'd say this is a encoding problem?

Comment: ? If for some reason you can't get this information on your own, you can simply ask your hoster for their environment configuration. You can still get very close (all but the apache configs), but I understand that this is harder to do. Is your host in your region (is it a German/whichever-country-you-are-from host)?

Comment: Yeah alright. So I would have the same problem on my local environment. 
I've upgraded ee from 2.7 to 2.10 and in the older version I haven't had this problem.